# Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 7 Network: Network password doesn't work

Tags: networking, windows, password

Look: http://youtu.be/W3J_C4wCt7k

When I try to access my Windows 7 pc, it ask for a password, I typed in the same password of the "Home Group" in Windows, but it doesn't work...

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure about the password you have entered is correct password for the user in windows 7 ? , What you can try is create a new user from windoows 7 with a simple username and password and try to login with that username and password and if its possible then I seriously doubt on previous credentials you have given.

Comment: Ok, sry my silliness, it works now...